# Strange lines appearing instead of cells when rendering jupyter notebook from a remote server

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, remote-server, jupyter-lab

Strange lines instead of cells appear when rendering jupyter notebook on a jupyterlab session from a remote Ubuntu linux server to a Windows machine. These lines don't disappear even when I refresh the page, clear cache and cookies, restart kernel and cleared all outputs, or even if copied to a local machine and sent back to the remote machine and rendered again from the remote machine. I need to run my jupyter-lab session from the remote server since I'm dealing with a lot of data which is stored on the remote machine.
In the below screenshot, each such line is a cell.

[jupyter notebook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJvxh.png)

Comment: What version of JupyterLab do you have installed? A bug causing that was fixed in JupyterLab 3.1.10, you may be using an outdated patch release.

Comment: yes, thanks. I had jupyter lab 3.1.9 installed. now have upgraded.